# IphoneX Safe Area leads to hidden content while using PageViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

Issues with safe area and page view, i wasn't able to post the question because stackoverflow was giving me an error about "code" but i include no code so i instead posted images, please refer to the below images thanks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Not sure I 100% understand your question, but try checking “Use Safe Area Layout Guides” in addition to “Use Auto Layout" and “Use Trait Variations."

Answer (score 0):

Auto layout behaves strangely sometimes. When It isn't working for me, there is a few things I do to try and resolve it which may or may not be useful to you:
I

1. duplicate the view controller so anything I do is isolated to that
   instance only.
2. Set the new (duplicated) view controller to be initial one.
3. Remove all constraints
4. Run the app and view on your phone to check the result.
5. Possibly shift + command + K to clean the app cache, as sometimes little glitches occur when a lot of minor auto layout changes have been made.
6. Run the app again and see if there was any changes.
7. Introduce any auto layout features one at a time and run the app between to see it's heading in the right direction.

I have found that doing it on another view controller and following at least a variation on the above procedure usually resolves most of the auto layout issues as you are describing.
Best of luck and I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

So i don't understand why but the fix for this was to add a pageViewHolder view on the uiviewcontroller that is presenting the viewcontroller, and than setup the constraints with a constant of 1 for the bottom like so

```
self.pageViewHolder.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: (self.pageController?.view)!, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.pageViewHolder, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 1.0));
```

Also NOTE that the pageViewHolder is constrained to the superviews bottom not safelayout.